# How to open PDF to browser on download when using syncfusion pdf creator?

Tags: flutter, pdf, syncfusion

I'm building a Flutter web app targeting Chrome that builds a PDF using [SyncFusion's Flutter PDF package](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf).

The following code creates a simple report and downloads it to the user's browser without any errors or warnings.  Once downloaded it can be opened by my user, but I'd rather make it open immediately or ask to be opened.

Question: How would I change this code to immediately open the PDF in the user's browser?

Here's my code:

```
  Future<void> createHoursReportPdf(DateTime reportDate) async {

  String reportTitle = "Hours Report for reportDate";

  // Create a PDF document.
  PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();

  // Add a page and draw text
  document.pages.add().graphics.drawString(
      reportTitle,
      PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 20),
      brush: PdfSolidBrush(PdfColor(0, 0, 0)),
      bounds: const Rect.fromLTWH(20, 60, 600, 30));

  // Save the document
  List<int> bytes = await document.save();

  // Dispose the document
  document.dispose();

  // Download the output file - Requires import 'dart:html';
  AnchorElement(
      href:
      "data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,${base64.encode(bytes)}")
    ..setAttribute("download", "output.pdf")
    ..click();
}
```

I tried changing `..setAttribute("download", "output.pdf")` to `..setAttribute("inline", "output.pdf")` but that only makes the downloaded PDF to be named "download" with no PDF extension.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To open the PDF directly in the browser, we can use window.open in dart:html package. The window.open method is used to open the PDF in a new browser window. Note that browser settings, pop-up blockers, and user preferences may affect the success of this approach. Additionally, some browsers may still prompt the user to download the file due to security restrictions.
Use the following code to import “dart:html”,

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
```

Use the following openPdfInBrowser method to open PDF in new browser window,

```
 Future<void> createHoursReportPdf(DateTime reportDate) async {
 String reportTitle = "Hours Report for $reportDate";
 
 // Create a PDF document.
 PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();
 
 // Add a page and draw text
 document.pages.add().graphics.drawString(
     reportTitle,
      PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 20),
     brush: PdfSolidBrush(PdfColor(0, 0, 0)),
     bounds: const Rect.fromLTWH(20, 60, 600, 30));
 
 // Save the document
 List<int> bytes = await document.save();
 
 // Dispose the document
 document.dispose();
 
 // Launch the PDF in the browser.
  openPdfInBrowser(Uint8List.fromList(bytes));
}
 
void openPdfInBrowser(Uint8List bytes) {
 final blob = html.Blob([bytes], 'application/pdf');
 final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
 html.window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Kindly use the following link to download the working sample for reference,
[pdf_demo_sample](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/pdf_demo_sample_61132651276.zip)